# How to make struct and typealias conform to @objc

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Is it possible to make a `struct` and/or `typealias` conform to `@objc`? I wish to create optional protocol functions, one returns a `struct`, the other a `typealias`.

```
public typealias SwiperData = (image: UIImage, title: String)

public struct SwiperPeekViewControllers{
  public var parentViewController: UIViewController!
  public var contentViewController: UIViewController!
  public init(parentVC: UIViewController, contentVC: UIViewController){
    parentViewController = parentVC
    contentViewController = contentVC
  }
}
```

**protocol**

```
    @objc public protocol SwiperPeekViewDelegate: class{
      func didUndoAction(index: Int, dataSource: SwiperData) 
// Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C
      func swiperPeekViewControllers()->SwiperPeekViewControllers
      func swiperPeekViewSize()->CGSize
    }
```

Comment: A Swift struct is a value type, and cannot be made compatible with an Objective-C object, which is a reference type.

Comment: See [Swift Type Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53) section in the _Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C_ guide, which precludes certain Swift constructs from being used from Objective-C, including "Structures defined in Swift", "Typealiases defined in Swift", and "Tuples".

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Rob

Comment: By the way, if you just wanted to make a method optional, sometimes you can achieve something similar by implementing a protocol extension that provides a default implementation of the required method. That way, the class that conforms to the protocol doesn't necessarily have to implement the method, just overriding it if needed. Personally, I'd only do that if a default implementation made logical sense (not, for example, doing a NOOP). Maybe you can describe the functional intent of a class conforming to `SwiperPeekViewDelegate` but not implementing the methods, and we can advise further.

Comment: I ended up following the examples provided in the reference given by converting the struct and type alias to NSObject classes with public initializers

Answer (score 4):

You can't export typealiases to Objective-C. And you can't do it for tuples. But, about `typealias`, it's still possible to write Obj-C `typedef` for some struct and use it from Swift, it will be exported as `typealias`

Comment: Can you share this "...Obj-C typedef for some struct and use it from Swift..." as an example, please.